# Wordpress Multisite Medial Library not working for .online domain

Tags: multisite, media-library

I have a wordpress multisite domain setup (subdirectory setup) and all the domains have been working fine (all end in .com). I've recently added a domain ending in .online. When I visit the media page for this domain only, the wait spinner keeps spinning. When I look at the chrome tools, the console shows an error retrieving the ajax.php file (404 error) in this format [domain-name].online/[domain-name].online/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. I tried disabling all the plugins and changing the theme to no avail. One difference I notice is that in the listing of sites, all the sites start with https://[domain].com. With this site, it starts with ://[domain].online. Adding the "https" string and clicking save changes doesn't change anything (i.e. it still shows "://..."). Any ideas?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Hello and welcome to WordPress SE. I fully understand your frustration - I hate it when a problem stubbornly refuses to be solved. I fear that this question might get flagged for removal as in its current state it would be hard to give a definitive answer without some more back and forth with you. Consider checking the sub-site config and reporting the important domain-related parts along with anything else you have tried and what the outcome was. You might even stumble on the answer while you are looking.

Comment: Try navigating to `[domain-name].online/[domain-name].online/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and see if you get a 404 too. If you do, try `[domain-name].online/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and see if that works. This should give you some debugging clues.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It was the :// issue. Using a sql editor, I saw that the site was pointing to https:///[domain].online. Not sure why changing that in the wordpress admin interface did not fix it, but removing the extra slash in the database fixed it.